# spacing in alerts

Tags: ios, xcode

Quick question:

```
message:@"This is a great website for maths exercises!! Have fun!! If you prefer to view the website in Safari just press 'Safari'"
```

Is there any way to add a new paragraph (or line break) between !! and if, and add "Safari""?

Answer (score 1):

```
@"This is a great website for maths exercises!! Have fun!!\n\rIf you prefer to view the website in Safari just press \"Safari\""
```

you'll also be fine with:

```
@"This is a great website for maths exercises!! Have fun!!\nIf you prefer to view the website in Safari just press \"Safari\""
```

Comment: an old habbit from Windows... CR & LF :) - some terminals would also just go to the next line without jumping back to 1st column